# Import list from separate file during runtime

Tags: flutter, file, dart

### Problem Explanation

I have a file that looks like this:

myfile1.txt

```
[
  {
    "question": "Thanks for the help",
    "answer choices": [
      "Hi",
      "stack",
      "over",
      "flow",
    ],
  },
  ...
]
```

This file contains data that needs to be set to a variable in a separate Dart file. The file type of this data does not matter, so if a .dart file would be easier to work with that would be perfectly fine.

Example of dart file that calls for the above file:

main.dart

```
void main() {

  List<Map<String, dynamic>> data;

  for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    data = getFile("myfile$i.txt");
    // Does stuff here
  }

}
```

Note: `getFile()` does not actually have to be used. It's just a placeholder for the example.

**Question:** How would I set the data in this file to the variable `data` while in a function (like `main()`).

### My attempt

Ideally, I wouldn't want to make many changes to the data file but here is what I did:

myfile1.dart

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> data = [
  ...
]
```

I changed the file type to a .dart file and created a variable that would be set to the data.

I then modified my main.dart file like so:

main.dart

```
void main() {

  for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    import "myfile$i.dart";
    // Does stuff here
  }

}
```

This approach fails because import cannot be called from inside a function.

Comment: I think all of the files should be imported before runtime.

Comment: If you are used `.txt` file then you should be add this in your `asset` folder and then called it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the word `import` there.  It's reserved word, used for loading flutter/dart packages, class files, etc.  It's not for "loading" some arbitrary data from a file.

Flutter official website has a [cookbook example for reading and writing data](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files) from and to files.  Perhaps their example would work for you?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't JavaScript.  Before any of the program is running, all the potential Dart code must have already been compiled.  You don't get to keep compiling Dart into anything after the first step of main() is active.